# Why echo's output needs to be separately put in quotes for placeholder's string in input field?

Tags: php, html, input, echo, placeholder

I am generating a string for placeholder dynamically via PHP echo function & if I don't put quotes around PHP tags the output only takes the first word of the string. Why so?

1. `placeholder=<?php echo "Hello World"?>`
   It outputs only Hello in input field
2. `placeholder="<?php echo "Hello World"?>"`(Note quotes around PHP tags)
   It outputs Hello World in input field.

Same also happens for value attribute of the input field.

Comment: Well I think `placeholder="<?php echo "Hello World"?>"` this will return error. Because you are not escaping `"`

Comment: No this is not giving any error. As @MinistryOfChaps also told below,the output of echo doesn't contain any quotes

Comment: I am talking regarding php file. Try your second example I exactly in php. It will throw syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to how the `placeholder` attribute is constructed.

You should conform to the standard of putting your value in between quotation marks (see [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) as proof).

It requires the values to be put in between quotations if you wish to add spaces to your value.

So imagine when you do this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder=<?php echo "Hello World"?> >
```

You are returning this in the HTML file:

```
<input type="text" placeholder=Hello World >
```

It reads 'Hello' as it's value and then HTML sees 'World' as another attribute. This is why you need to put your value in between quotes to signify that the entire string is apart of the `placeholder` attribute.

Comment: So doesn't echo output as "Hello World" (with double quotes) as output of echo is a string & strings are supposed to be in between double quotes?

Comment: @NishantGarg when you `echo` a string, it only outputs what is between the quotations, not the quotations themselves. That is why you must encapsulate your PHP echo with quotation marks in the HTML quotes (like you did with `placeholder="<?php echo "Hello World"?>"`). Try echoing Hello World on a seperate PHP file and you will see there is no quotation marks around the text.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for the first case, the render will output

```
placeholder=hello world
```

As, there is no quotes, it will consider the first word as the value of placeholder(But it is a bad practise).
Second case is good because it has quotations

```
placeholder="hello world"
```

So you need to care about how your output will be.

Answer (score 0):

For the First Case

`placeholder=<?php echo "Hello World"?>`

will just output it like so

`placeholder=Hello World`

And this is not a valid HTML format 
but the second one

`placeholder="<?php echo "Hello World"?>"`

Enter code here will output

`placeholder="Hello World"`

which is valid so always go with the second one.

And if you just echo a string you can do it like that

`<?="hello world" ?>`